# AML service scoring using environment object

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

How do we specify supporting source folders during scoring using Environments object.
Support there are multiple dependency files (like utils) and I have places them in a folder under source-directory, will the files get loaded to the image?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the files under the source_directory, as specified in the [InferenceConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py), they should get mounted within the container.

You can also bake the files into the image itself, by specifying [custom Docker build steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments#enable-docker) for the Environment, for example `RUN wget <url to my files>` to get the files from a web location.